# using cmd in powershell properly

Tags: powershell

at the moment i install a programm to a remote machine with batch. thats already working fine.
but how can i use or "convert" the batch command below in powershell using the specific command for the prgramm to install it silent on the remote machine?
this is my batch code.

```
set /p target=hostname 
echo.
copy /z "\\server1\tool.exe" "\\%target%\C$\temp"
echo.
PsExec.exe \\%target% cmd /c "\\%target%\C$\temp\tool.exe" /verysilent
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: The only lines you need to change are `set /p` to a `Read-Host`, and the parameter for `copy`. The rest should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$target=hostname
Copy-Item -Path "\\server1\tool.exe" -Destination "\\$target\C$\temp"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock \\%target%\C$\temp\tool.exe -ComputerName $target -credential (USERNAME)
```

for the `Invoke-Command` `-Scriptblock` is the command you want to run, `-ComputerName` is the computer you want to start a process on, `-Credential` is the username to use to run the command. You will automatically be prompted to enter your password.

Answer (score 0):

Thanky guys for your answers.
i did like that

```
$target = Read-Host "hostname"
Copy-Item -Path "\\server1\tool.exe" -Destination "\\$target\C$\temp"
PsExec.exe \\$target -s winrm.cmd quickconfig -q
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $target -ScriptBlock {
cmd /c "C:\temp\tool.exe" /verysilent
}
```